# Deploying Python script on a Web Server

Tags: python, api, flask, server, celery

I have made a Project in **Python 3.6.3** which has two main modules which are-

- **[OpenCv](https://www.opencv.org/about.html) *(opencv-python==3.4.0.12)***
- **[TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/) *(tf-nightly==1.8.0.dev20180329)***

It is as of now running on my Local machine. I want to deploy it on a web server as a **Website** by means of **Flask**. I know I can call my main script *i.e.* `main.py` in my `Flask.py`*(created just to give an idea)*

**Flask.py**

```
from flask import Flask
import main # Main Python Script

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def my_script():
    main.some_func()
    ........
.......
.......
.......


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.secret_key = 'super_secret_key'
    app.debug = True
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

I went through some links and got to know about [Celery](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/celery/) and [This](https://www.linode.com/docs/applications/big-data/how-to-move-machine-learning-model-to-production/) link *(It is for Keras and I am using Tensorflow)* here it is given to deploy the model as an **API**.

So I am having a hard time to figure out how should I deploy my project either as a Website or as an API.

- **If as a Website**, then what measures should I take? should I just simply call the function or use *Celery*?
- **And If as an API**, then wouldn't I need one web server for my API and another for my Website?

*(I may be wrong on my conclusions)*

Anyone kindly please tell me how to approach this. Thank You!

Comment: Who is going to use your machine learning tool? And how long does one call to your function take?

Comment: Faculty of my university. My script gives the output on an average in 25-30 seconds @syntonym

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general:

You can do both: you can run WebServer AND API in the same machine. It is only matter of getting your proxy settings right. API calls can be made from your server, too. And API helps to keep your MVC architecture straight.

You can have later separate server for your API and your WebServer, if there is some adverse effects (performance issues) between those.

Biggest disadvantage with API approach is performance loss, but then you can still code scripts in your WebServer that bypass it, too.

---

For Keras, Tensorflow or any AI implementation I highly recommend to have separate server, because that is resource intensive (needs lots of GPU power, when training) and web server is more CPU hungry (more or less steady load).

But before going to production generic approach could be still feasible.

Comment: Actually, I am using CPU version for Tensorflow and my main script just makes a single call to my machine learning module and my script gives an output in about 30 seconds or 40 seconds maximum. So would it still slow down things if I implement my flask app as I mentioned in the code stub in my question? @Mika72

Comment: And which approach will be generic? @Mika72

Comment: In general/generic (when deploying any web service) is until horizontal line in my answer. For AI-using web service starting from "For Keras, ..." onwards.